# Does Zend PHP code have to be changed to run on community PHP?

Tags: ibm-midrange

The license to use `zend php server basic` [is ending June 30, 2021](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/php-ibm-i).

Will the following code run on IBM i [community PHP](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/php-ibm-i)?

```
function as400Connect($libl)
{
  $options = array('i5_naming' => DB2_I5_NAMING_ON);
  if (strlen($libl) > 0)
  {
    $options['i5_libl'] = $libl ;
  }
  $conn = db2_connect("*LOCAL", "", "", $options);
  if (!$conn) {
    echo "Connection failed";
    echo "<br>";
    echo db2_conn_errormsg();
    exit();
  }
  return $conn;
}
```

The code uses the db2_ functions.  And it relies on the `i5_libl` option to set the library list on the server job. Setting the library list is critical when my PHP web applications call SQL stored procedures on the IBM i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in luck! Although I'm not sure about the distribution at the link you provided, our [CommunityPlus+ PHP](https://www.seidengroup.com/communityplus-php-for-ibm-i/) definitely supports the ibm_db2 and i5_libl option. We're official maintainers of the ibm_db2 component.

See [this article in IT Jungle](https://www.itjungle.com/2021/01/11/seiden-group-unveils-a-php-distro-for-ibm-i/) for more.

Comment: just to be clear, will community PHP run the db2_ functions?

Comment: @RockBoro CommunityPlus+ PHP at the link I posted above runs the db2_ functions perfectly. I can't speak about other community versions (Zend's community PHP didn't run db2_ last time I checked), but this one does.